# How to call a private function from a string in javascript?

Tags: javascript, oop

I'm building a small "Validate" object which basically exposes a validate method and takes the id of one element and an array of validators and then returns true or false.

basically this is what i'd like to achieve

```
var Validator = function() {
  var no_digits = function( el ) {
      return true;
  }
  var no_uppercase_letters = function( el ) {
      return true;
  }
  return {
     validate: function( element_id, validators ) {

        //here i would like to iterate on the validators array and for each 
        //element of the array i would like to check if a function of the same name 
        // exist and call that function passing the element      

     }
  }
}();
```

and then call it like this

```
var element_valid = Validator.validate( 'myid', [ "no_digits", "no_uppercase_letters"] );
```

where the second parameter is an array of validators i'd like to call.

Any suggestion on a good object oriented approach?I would like to keep the validating functions private otherwise i could do

```
var Validator = function() {


    return {
        validate: function(element_id, validators) {
            console.log(this);
            this[validators]();

            // Validator[validators](element_id);     
        },
        no_digits: function(el) {
            alert('hi');
            return true;
        },
        no_uppercase_letters:  function(el) {
            return true;
        }
    }
}();
```

but i'd rather keep the no_gits an no_uppercase_letters function private

var element_valid = Validator.validate('myid', "no_digits");

Comment: I didn't quite understand what are you asking. Your code looks fine to me...

Comment: In javascript you can actually pass functions as parameters. So you probably should pass second argument as [validateNoDigits, validateNoUppercaseLetters], where elements in array are functions.

Comment: @gdoron basically i want to iterate on the array and call the function that has the same name of the variable. I edited my question

Comment: Well, you can refer to the methods of an object through strings as well. `validator["no_digits"]()` is the same as `validator.no_digits();`

Comment: @Imp i need to do that inside the validate() method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var valdiate = (function() {  

     var _p={};//toss all private members into a single object.
     _p.list=[];
     _p.init=function(){
       _p.list=[];
     };

    var noDigits = function() {

    };

    //public members. use "this" to reference object followed by the method.
    //however valdiate._p.list won't be accessible to the global scope    
    return {    
        check: function() {
              noDigits();
        },
        fnNaMe1:function(){
              _p.init();
        },
        fnName2:function(){
           return _p.list.slice(0);//return a clone  
        }
    };
})();
```

**It's called the "Module pattern".** This pattern is more commonly known as simply "**encapsulation**" in JavaScript. Closures is another possibly but more specifically it is purely encapsulation in this case.

Encapsulation simply means you are making some members private. What is private in this case? Well the `noDigits` variable is private in this case.

Comment: Yes i know this, but i need to call the noDigits method from the string "noDigits"

Comment: Yes it does!I need to declare an internal object where i have the private methods! Look at the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kSK4n/3/ and thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Would this approach work?
jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/FranWahl/KZKwA/ to play with.
Note that I didn't implement any of the actual validation but the basic framework does execute.

```
var Validator = function() {
    return {
        validate: function(element_id, validators) {
            for (var i = 0; i < validators.length; i++) {
                var result = validators[i](element_id);
                alert(result);
                // record results... or do something else with it or break; etc...
            }
        }
    }
}();

var no_digits = function(theValue) {
    // validate no digits are in the given value....
    if(theValue === '1')
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
};

var no_uppercase_letters = function(theValue) {
    // validate no uppercase letters are in this value...
    if(theValue === '4')
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
};

// I used variables to store the methods but feel free to declare the methods inline instead...
var element_valid = Validator.validate('4', [no_digits , no_uppercase_letters]);​
```

Comment: This would work but i'd rather keep the other functions hidden so that i don't use the global namespace. This does that but i would like to keep the methods private http://jsfiddle.net/kSK4n/2/

Comment: Using strings instead of the function signatures is not OO (IMHO) and I took from your post you wanted an OO approach. You can separate the validators out into a separate class. That way you can let developers either use the validators individually as needed or call your helper method, passing an array of them they would like to combine.

Comment: Yep, maybe i expressed myself in the worng manner, your method is ok in fact (i just need to use namespaces and i'm ok) i just wondered if i could use also the other approach! :)

Comment: In that case I'm note sure how to check your object has a function with the name specified in the string, Sorry I couldn't help more :(